# If a continuous function is positive on a closed interval $I$, there exists a positive number $\alpha$ such that $f(x) > \alpha$ for all $x\in I$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Could someone please explain to me how I am supposed to how I am supposed to approach this question:

Let $I = [a,b]$ and $f:I\mapsto \Bbb R$ be a continuous function on $I$ such that $\forall x\in I,f(x) > 0$. Prove that there exist a number $\alpha$ such that $\forall x\in I,f(x) > \alpha$.

I really have a tough time solving questions like these since I dont understand how I am supposed to start, so if someone of you are experienced could you please give me some tips about how I can possibly become better in proving such statements.

Comment: Have you proved the theorem that a continuous function on a closed bounded interval attains its maximum and minimum?

Comment: yes I have, how should I use that theorem?

Comment: It might be important to specify $\alpha\gt 0$, otherwise, I could choose $\alpha=-1$...

Comment: @BilalJunaidy: Is [this user](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/201131/bilal-junaidy) also you? If so, please follow the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 2):

From the theorem I cited in the comment, you have that $f(x)$ attains it's minimum on $I$. Call that minimum$b$. Can you see that $b \gt 0$? Now let $\alpha=$ what?

Comment: Okay, so b > 0 since f(x) > 0 for all x in I therefore f(x_k) = b > 0 for some x_k in I, right? is this the correct rational. and I will let alpha = b/2, that works, right? and Thanks for the help

Comment: Your statement about $x_k$ is correct but not needed. Yes $\alpha=b/2$ Works fine

Comment: Thanks Ross, okay, so I am new to this website but I know that I can increase your reputation by voting for you or something like that, so how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: To the left of each question and answer are up and down arrows for you to vote. You can vote on as many things as you want. You can also accept one answer to your question, indicating that the answer solved your problem. Don't be too quick to accept, as a better answer may come in